# Number of sets that contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and one digit

Tags: combinatorics

Let $ \Sigma = \{A,...,Z\} \cup \{a,...,z\} \cup \{0,...,9\} $.

I want to prove find the number of sets $ \Omega \subseteq \Sigma $ such that $ \Omega $ contains at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter and one digit. Are my calculations correct?

First choose a letter from $ \{A,...,Z\} $ - there are $ \binom{26}1 = 26 $ ways to do so.

Choose a letter from $ \{a,...,z\} $ - there are $ \binom{26}1 = 26 $ ways to do so.

Choose a digit from $ \{0,...,9\} $ - there are $ \binom{10}1 = 10 $ ways to do so. Overall, there are $ 10\cdot26^2 $ ways to choose an uppercase letter, a lowercase letter and a digit.

We're left with a set with $ 59 $ characters and therefore there are $ 10\cdot26^2\cdot2^{59} $ sets that satisfy the requirement.

Comment: I'm afraid you're counting some sets multiple times. Suppose for example that your first choice was Aa0 and then you selected 5,t,F. That yields the same result as selecting Ft5 at the start and then selecting A,a and 0, yet you're counting those separately.

Answer (score 2):

You are overcounting sets. Say we have the set $\Omega=\{A,B,c,6\}$. You count this set twice, because $Ac6$ or $Bc6$ can be chosen in the first draw. While you can account for this overcounting by considering each case individually, it would be a long and painful process. A better approach is the following:

We can choose at least one uppercase character in $(2^{26}-1)$ ways, at least one lowercase character in $(2^{26}-1)$ ways and at least one digit in $(2^{10}-1)$ ways. Because we wish to choose at least one uppercase character **and** at least one lowercase character **and** at least one digit, we have $$\text{Total no. of sets}=(2^{26}-1)(2^{26}-1)(2^{10}-1)$$